# Drive Objects Rotation depending on state of other objects sin and cos value

Tags: drivers

I started to get into Drives. I want one cube(green) to rotate 90° whenever the other cube(red) is doing it's last 90° turn on the way to the full 360°. Now i've come up with following Logic depending on the red cubes rotation(rot).

[when sin(rot)<0 and cos(rot)>0 add 90° to current rotation]

Can someone show me the right way to a working expression?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be done two ways :
***scripted expression :*** which should be one line of code and it may get complicated
***driver function :*** this will make it a lot easier to control and create complex driver, we define a function then use it in the scripted expression

---

**scripted expression :**

```
floor(b/(2*pi))*pi/2 + (cos(b)>0 and sin(b)<0)*(b-1.5*pi) + (b< 0)*2*pi
```

where b is the angle  of the red cube

[image]

---

**driver function:**

we define a new function `calc_angle()` and add it to the driver namespace, this function calculates the angle the same as the scripted expression but its easier to read, update and reuse in multiple drivers .
run the script in blender's text editor

```
import bpy
from math import *

two_pi = 2*pi
pi_two = pi/2

#create new function
def calc_angle(angle):

        new_angle = floor(angle/two_pi)*pi_two

        if cos(angle) > 0 and sin(angle) < 0 :                
            if angle > 0 :
                new_angle += angle-1.5*pi
            else :
                new_angle += two_pi + angle-1.5*pi
        return new_angle

#add the function to the driver namespace    
bpy.app.driver_namespace['calc_angle'] = calc_angle
```

and setup the driver as follows :

[image]

Comment: As always, a very good and understandable answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Järv you're welcome , I really like the animation in your question !